# C# - How do I set my winform to my country's current timezone

Tags: c#, mysql

I developed an timekeeping system made from c#.net (winform) and my database was uploaded to cpanel database. My question is, how do i set my application to my country's current timezone? (I'm living in Philippines) because when I'm using MYSQL now function, it's inserting wrong date time value because my host panel is based on American time. How do I fix this?

Comment: Unless you changed the culture, your app will be using your local culture and time zone.  Its more likely related to how you are storing the date and/or what you are passing.  Show that code after you read [ask] and take the [tour]

Comment: Please show us the code you are using to write to the database.

Comment: I'm just using now() function of mysql but it is inserting wrong date to database because my host panel (which is cpanel) is hosted to American while I'm living in the Philippines. How do i set my time zone like this in php manner: $myDateTime->setTimezone(new DateTimeZone('Asia/Kolkata'));

Comment: So what makes you think your Winforms App has the wrong timezone, or that changing it is the solution?  Its not even involved in anything to do with the date data being saved!

Comment: There are many ways to fix the issue. See [MySQL Server Time Zone Support](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/time-zone-support.html) for details.

Comment: Ha ha, you dont understand my problem. i developed an app and I am living on Ph so my timezone is based on Philippines but then again my database is uploaded to hosting site which is based on America. So whenever Im executing my insert query with now() function, it is inserting American time instead of my country's time. I know how to do that in PHP but in c#, i dont know.

Comment: Think what you are asking.  If the Server using En-us is providing the date, how will doing anything with the Winform App have any effect at all?  Most servers run UTC - and most such DB functions also save UTC (I am not sure if thats the case with that one)  - so I am not sure your diagnosis is correct.  Read [ask] and take the [tour]

Answer (score 1):

The MySQL [documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/datetime.html) says:

> MySQL converts TIMESTAMP values from the current time zone to UTC for storage, and back from UTC to the current time zone for retrieval.

So, you just need do use `TIMESTAMP` data type instead of `DATETIME` for column that stores your values of a row insert moment.